# In Eval function if some string variable is not their,how can i skip it

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict `x={'a':1,'b':2}` of this type.
I have one more dict where I stored formula

```
x1={'c':{'p':'pre','r':'ref','2010':'a+b'},'d': {'p':'pre','r':'ref','2010':'f+g'}
```

I am using eval to calculate formula. For this i am using code

```
for k,v in x1.iteritems():
   if eval(x1[k]['2010'],x) is False:
       continue
```

Actually value for "a" and "b" is their but values of "f" and "g" not their
`eval(x1['c']['2010'],x)` works but `eval(x1['d]['2010'],x)` fails, so i want to skip this evaluation. But it shows 'f' not defined.

Comment: What is this.. I don't even ..

Comment: @wim Actually in Text box i indented program by 4 spaces,but when i save it all comes in one line

Comment: @user1182090 You need to leave a blank line between a block formatted code and the context.

Comment: Now its formatted can anyone help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try:

```
for k,v in x1.iteritems():
    try:
        eval(x1[k]['2010'],x)
    except NameError:
       continue
```

But IMHO the concept is somewhat strange - or I just do not understand it...

BTW: a closing bracket is missing in the definition of x1.

Answer (score 1):

Why use `eval()`?  Why not just test for the value?
Also, since your using `.items()` you get the key and value, so you don't need to re-reference the dictionary.

```
for k, v in x.items():
    if not v:
        continue
```

Comment: I don't think he got your solution, unfortunately. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept you are missing: lambda expressions. They allow you to create single-expression functions.

So, instead of `eval('a+b', {'a':1,'b':2})`, you can do `(lambda a,b: a+b)(1,2)`. Lambda expressions (like functions) are first-class objects which can be held in a dict.